# Show spanish characters in a form

Tags: php, html, forms, character-encoding

I have a form and in a textarea I want to display some text that have some spanish characters but encoded as html. The problem is that instead of the spanish character it displays the html code. I'm using htmlentities to display it in the form. my code to display is:

```
<?php echo htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") ?>
```

Any idea or I just shouldnt use htmlentities in a form? Thanks!

**EDIT**
Lets say `$string = 'á'`

When I just do `<?php echo $string ;?>` I get `á`
If I do `<?php echo htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") ?>` I get `&aacute;`

I'm so confused!

Comment: Do you get your desired result if you replace htmlentities with [htmspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars.php) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try explicitly adding content type at the top of your file as below

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

if it's already encoded as html then you need to decode it now..you can use `html_entity_decode($string);`

Your string to be echoed in the form should be `&aacute;`  as returned from database and not `á`

```
$string = '&aacute;'; // your string as fetched from database
echo html_entity_decode($string);// this will display á in the textarea
```

and before saving to database you need to

```
htmlentities($_POST['txtAreaName'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); // return `&aacute;`
```

Comment: tried that and it doesnt work. For some reason, when I dont use htmlentities it displays ok, but once I use it, it seems like it encodes it twice.

Comment: if `<?php echo $string ;?>` echoes the right text then is there any further issue..??

Comment: I want to make sure I do htmlentities in case of xss attacks

Comment: `&aacute;` needs to be your `$string`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to use...

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

in your page header, and then...

```
<?php echo html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES); ?>
```

This will convert your HTML entities back to their proper characters

Comment: and make sure you have the right charset set to the page header:

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: I have all of this and nothing

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for htmlspecialchars.

```
echo htmlspecialchars('<á>', ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML5, "UTF-8");
```

outputs `&lt;á&gt;`.

Comment: Yes, right now it displays the html code, but its not displaying the user friendly one. Meaning, for á I get &aacute; . I would like it to display á but in the html for it to be &aacute;

Comment: Are you sure you aren't converting your & later again?

Comment: im sure, the html is only showing &aacute;, it would show &amp;aacute;

Comment: `ENT_HTML5` is redundant with htmlspecialchars, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14532168/427545